# Why are NSPredicate and DateComponents not working

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

Here I'm using an NSPredicate to get this week's Monday history from Core Data using an NSFetchRequest. I don't know why this isn't working can you please help me? I have the same code for Thursday, only the weekday is different, but for some reason it prints out the dates multiple time here is my code and I also attached the console:[image]

```
func getDateMonday(){
    
    let currentDate = Date()
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let weekOfMonth = calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: Date())
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: Date())
    
    let mondayComponentStart = DateComponents(month: month, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, weekday: 2, weekOfMonth: weekOfMonth)
    let mondayComponentEnd = DateComponents(month: month, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, weekday: 2, weekOfMonth: weekOfMonth )
    
    let lastMondayStart = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: currentDate,
                                              matching: mondayComponentStart,
                                              matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                              repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                                              direction: .backward) ?? Calendar.current.nextDate(after: currentDate, matching: mondayComponentStart, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward)
    let lastMondayEnd = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: currentDate,
                                              matching: mondayComponentEnd,
                                              matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                              repeatedTimePolicy: .first,
                                              direction: .forward) ?? Calendar.current.nextDate(after: currentDate, matching: mondayComponentEnd, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward)
    
    
    
    let predicateStart = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", lastMondayStart! as NSDate)
    let predicateEnd = NSPredicate(format: "date <= %@", lastMondayEnd! as NSDate)
    
    let allPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicateStart, predicateEnd])
    
    let waterFetch = NSFetchRequest<Water>(entityName: "Water")
    waterFetch.predicate = allPredicate

    do {
    print(lastMondayStart!)
    print(Date())
    print(lastMondayEnd!)
    print("------------------")
    let waterF = try viewContext.fetch(waterFetch)
      
            for all in waterF {
                
                let tot = all.amount
                monday += Int(tot)
                Total += Int(tot)
                
    }

    } catch {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The next Monday in the 4. week of March (`lastMondayEnd`) is in 2022. It's easier to add `DateComponents(day: 1, second: -1)`  to the start date or to find `23:59:59` after the start date

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do you know why does Thursday appear twice in the console, because if I delete it it will be another day appearing twice, specifically always the third from behind.

Comment: There are a few dates in 2022 which make no sense. Check your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was very stupid, because I mistyped one of the functions and I accidentally called one function twice